# heroku php nginx configuration

Tags: php, heroku, yii, nginx

I have a php application(Yii framework) that lives on Heroku. I am trying to get the nginx configuration set up properly so that the app serves correctly. Right now, it serves the PHP but not that static files. Below is my nginx configuration along with the command inside the Procfile. Any help is appreciated.

```
--Procfile--
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf

--nginx.conf--
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /myapp/public/index.php/$1 last;
}

location /css {
    alias /myapp/public/css/;
}

location /js {
    alias /myapp/public/js/;
}

location /img {
    alias /myapp/public/img/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  heroku-fcgi;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a static file that isn't being served? Like `example.com/assets/js/jquery.min.js`...

Comment: FYI, [docs for the `try_files` directive in nginx (link)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: @ALtheX thanks for the information, I was able to finally figure it out from Google ;D

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting everything working with this config below:

```
location / {
    root /app/myapp/public;

    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /myapp/public/index.php/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the last section; that's in the outer default config already.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't define the document root like this. Use the following:

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
    
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 last;
    }

And in your `Procfile`, use `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf myapp/public/` (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root)

Comment: @dzuelke, I had tried many things but I'm still having a problem. Do you have something to accrescent here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418400/router-not-working-heroku-nginx-php-phalcon?