# Router not working (Heroku + Nginx + PHP Phalcon)

Tags: heroku, nginx, phalcon

I don't get it why the mvc routes are not working.

When I access the home page, all the css and js are loaded.

```
"GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304
```

But when I access any other controller, I got:

```
method=GET path="/transaction/add"
[error] open() "/app/public/transaction/add" failed (2: No such file or directory)
"GET /transaction/add HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Here's my procfile

```
--Procfile--
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx public/

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    internal;
}
```

I'm really lost here.

Comment: Sorry, I use Apache, but this seem to be contradictory : # rewrite all to app.php VS rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last; You may try with app.php instead of index.php, or else with public/index.php

Comment: @KyleK, just to update I have made some changes, but nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    internal;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this to, but I had no success. Maybe the problem is that the Procfile aren't reading my /public/index.php, but not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the instructions in the documentation: http://docs.phalconphp.com/fr/latest/reference/nginx.html

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name localhost.dev;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $root_path '/var/www/phalcon/public';
    root $root_path;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did and I got "Mod-Rewrite not enabled. Please enable rewrite urls on your web server to continue". Where that was my first problem. Any idea?

Comment: What is your path (instead of /var/www/phalcon/public) and do it contains index.php?

Comment: I had executed "heroku run bash" and I saw that the path is "app/public" where inside I have the index.php. Just to be clear app folder max root that i can get, there's no folder with the project named inside of it.

Comment: app may be the FTP root but not the machine root, you must replace /var/www/phalcon/public with the absolute public path, display `dirname(__FILE__)` to get it.

Comment: same thing: "/app". Any other idea?